# Why this C programm return another result then expected?

Tags: c

I have to write a C programm, which should print an address which are delivering to a kind of constructor. This constructor receives a pointer of the struct object and the parts of the adress as parameters.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Adress
{
    char *name;
    char *street;
    int number;
    int postalcode;
    char *city;

};
void Adress(struct Adress *that, char *name, char *street, int number, int postalcode, char *city)
    {
        that->name       = name;
        that->street     = street;
        that->number     = number;
        that->postalcode = postalcode;
        that->city       = city;
    }

     void print(struct Adress *that)
    {
        printf("%s\n%s %d\n", that->name, that->street, that->number);
        printf("%d %s\n", that->postalcode, that->city);
    }
int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
    struct Adress* adr1 =(struct Adress*) malloc(sizeof(struct Adress) + 100);
    struct Adress* that1 = (struct Adress*) &adr1;
    Adress(that1, "John Doe", "Street", 1, 1234, "City");


    struct Adress* adr2 = (struct Adress*) malloc(sizeof(struct Adress));
    struct Adress* that2 = (struct Adress*) &adr2;
    Adress(that2, "Jane Doe", "Street", 1, 1234, "City");

    print(that1);
    print(that2);


    free(adr2);
    free(adr1);
}
```

The programm should print:
John Doe
Street 1
1234 City

respectively
Jane Doe
Street 2
1234 City

but instead of it displays:

(null)
(null) 0
0 (null)

What did I do wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: `struct Adress* that1 = (struct Adress*) &adr1;` is invalid. Why do you do that? What  do you think it means?

Comment: I want to create the pointer that1, which points to the reference of adr1. I made this without the cast at the beginning but this caused an error.

Comment: "Reference" isn't a thing in C.

Comment: `adr1` is already a pointer which points to the address struct. A pointer to a pointer would have type `struct Adress **`. Remove the casts and you should get a compiler warning – heed those warnings, don't silence them by casting. The compiler generally knows the correct type better than you.

Comment: So you want a pointer to a pointer, such as `struct Adress **that1 = &adr1;`?

Comment: (But you don't need a pointer to a pointer for anything you are doing here, and if you plan to add something where you would need it, you can usually just pass `&adr1` directly without saving it in an intermediate variable.)

Comment: Meanwhile if this confusion about "reference" comes from some tutorial that you are following, are you sure it is not talking about C++ (which is a very different language than C)?

Comment: Your code should work if you change `struct Adress* this1 = (struct Adress*) &adr1;` to `struct Adress* this1 = adr1;`, and similarly for `this2` with `adr2`. But you could just replace `this1` with `adr1` and `this2` with `adr2` in the calls to `Addres()` and `print()`.

Comment: Using the same name for a type and a function is ... also unusual. But I agree that you simply don't need `that1` and `that2` at all, you can just use `adr1` and `adr2` directly.

Comment: Sorry, I don't mean reference, I mean the address. I want a pointer which point to the instances of the struct (so adr1 respectively adr2). I don't want a pointer to a pointer.

Comment: `malloc` returns a pointer to the memory already...

Comment: @IanAbbott It works now, thank you!